# Eigenstates of helicity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

For massless particles, we can take as reference the vector $p^{\mu}_R=(1,0,0,1)$ and note that any vector $p$ can be written as $p^{\mu}=L(p)^{\mu}_{\nu}p^{\nu}_R$, where $L(p)$ is the Lorentz transformation of the form

$L(p)=exp(i\phi J^{(21)})exp(i\theta J^{(13)})exp(i\alpha J^{(30)})$

Where $(\theta,\phi)$ are the spherical coordinates of $\vec{p}$ and $\alpha=sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}(p^0-1/p^0))$. This allows to define the general state for the massless particle as:

$|p,\lambda\rangle=U(L(p))|p_R,\lambda\rangle$

Which is an eigenstate with value $\lambda$ of the helicity operator $\frac{\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|}\cdot\vec{J}$.

I'm trying to verify this last statement by expanding the exponentials or using commutators, but I can't seem to arrive at the result. Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: If you have the operator and one of its eigenvectors, have you tried acting the operator on the known eigenvector to find the scalar eigenvalue?

Comment: Yeah, that was actually the first thing I tried: $(\frac{\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|}\cdot\vec{J})U(L(p))|p_R,\lambda\rangle)=(\frac{\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|}\cdot\vec{J})U(exp(i\phi J^{(21)})exp(i\theta J^{(13)})exp(i\alpha J^{(30)}))|p_R,\lambda\rangle$. However, I don't find a way to reduce it to the eigenvalue.

Comment: $\vec p\cdot\vec J$ is invariant under spatial rotations, and therefore so are its eigenvales. Just pick a convenient frame of reference.